# Joining an Ubuntu 14.04 machine to active directory with realm and sssd

Tags: 14.04, server, active-directory

I've tried following this guide to set up realmd and sssd with active directory: http://funwithlinux.net/2014/04/join-ubuntu-14-04-to-active-directory-domain-using-realmd/

When I run the command `realm –verbose join domain.company.com –user-principal=c-u14-dev1/nwalke@DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM –unattended` everything seems to connect.  My sssd.conf looks like the following:

```
[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root
reconnection_retries = 3

[pam]
reconnection_retries = 3

[sssd]
domains = DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM]
ad_domain = DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
krb5_realm = DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
access_provider = ad
```

My `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` looks like this:

```
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

I'm able to log in with `nwalke/DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM`, how do I change these configs so that I can log in with just `nwalke`?

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate.  My problem deals with realm and sssd.  I will use the info about creating home directories, however.  Removed this from my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Redhat's SSSD Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sssd-user-ids.html):

> Setting a default domain name allows users to log in with only their username, not specifying the domain name (which would be required for users outside the primary domain).

So, under the `[sssd]` section of the configuration file, set the field `default_domain_suffix` to be blank. Keep in mind that if there is a user on the local system and domain server, the local user will take priority.